# apex:pageBlockSectionItem collaspe or expand throws "twistSection is not defined" JavaScript exception

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have an [apex:pageBlockSection](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSection.htm) defined within an apex:component. The component is used within an apex:pageBlock of a Visualforce page. It isn't rendered when the page initially loads.

When a user presses the the arrow on the page block section a JavaScript error is thrown.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: twistSection is not defined

[image: twistSection is not defined]

**Why is this Salesforce JavaScript function missing?**

I did find the `twistSection` function defined on another page. It was defined in a script element of the HTML page (rather than an external script).
[image: twistSection function]

I guess I could copy this script definition into my component and define the missing function myself if required. My only concern is <strike>if</strike> when Salesforce updates their script mine will break.

The other backup plan is to put `collapsible="false"` on the pageBlockSection. Feels a bit like admitting defeat though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an experiment I added a mock `apex:pageBlockSection` immediately after the `apex:pageBlock` on the page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">

            <!-- HACK: Fake pbSection to inject the twistSection JS function -->
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Test" showHeader="true" rendered="false">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputText value="Label" />
                    <apex:outputText value="Value" />
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

           <!-- Existing content -->

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This seemed sufficient to get Salesforce to inject the missing JavaScript function. Note that it didn't need to be rendered to get the script defined.

Answer (score 2):

For me only adding this line worked.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Test" rendered="false"></apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I am not sure the collapsable will be deprecated but not sure why doing that. Remember it was working on api 27.0

Answer (score 0):

I had this error even when I had the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` in the code. What helped me was I had the attribute mode="edit" within `<apex:pageBlockSection>`, when i took it out, it worked fine. Just in case anyone else runs into it.